# react-router index route always active

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to style my navigation by using the react `activeClassName` attribute. So far it works as expected, but there is a problem - my first nav links points to the root route(/). So even when on another URL it will register that URL (for example /skills) and root as active (so 2 menu items get styled).

Is there an easy workaround for this? Should I just define the Root route as something else (for example /home)?

My header:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router';

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className="header">
            <div className="headerImage"></div>
            <ul className="headerNav">
                <li className="headerNavLink"><Link to="/" activeClassName="activeLink">introduction</Link></li>
                <li className="headerNavLink"><Link to="/skills" activeClassName="activeLink">skills</Link></li>
                <li className="headerNavLink"><Link to="/portfolio" activeClassName="activeLink">portfolio</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

routes.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
//Import app
import App from './components/App';
//Import pages
import IntroductionPage from './components/introduction/IntroductionPage';
import SkillsPage from './components/skills/SkillsPage';
import PortfolioPage from './components/portfolio/PortfolioPage';

//Define routes
export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={IntroductionPage} />
        <Route path="skills" component={SkillsPage} />
        <Route path="portfolio" component={PortfolioPage} />
    </Route>
);
```

So to clarify, I would like my home route to not be active when on another route.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd like to [reference the docs for React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool) (`react-router-dom`, currently v5) and the [sources](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/NavLink.js).
This is **the up-to-date way to implement this**:

> **exact**: bool
>
> When true, the active class/style will only be applied if the location is matched exactly.

```
<NavLink exact to="/profile">
  Profile
</NavLink>
```

Here is a real world working example:

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <NavLink className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" to="/" exact>Home</NavLink>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <NavLink className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" to="/calendar">Calendar</NavLink>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <NavLink className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" to="/page">Page</NavLink>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: accepting this as the correct anwser since it references an up-to-date solution.

Comment: Thanks for the saving the day 

Answer (score 14):

Just like also to share this if you use "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",

```
export const routes = <Index>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/about' component={About} />
</Index>;
```

Then your navigation menu is

```
<NavLink exact={true} activeClassName='active' to="/">
   Home
</NavLink>
<NavLink activeClassName='active' to="/bout">
    About
</NavLink>
```

Just specify also the "exact={true}" props for the NavLink and it should work as expected.

Thanks, Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. What I have learned is that 'exact' props in Route help in matching path before loading component while 'exact' props in NavLink help in matching path before applying 'active' class to <a> tag.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`<IndexLink>`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#indexlink) or set `onlyActiveOnIndex` prop for links that are not to be highlighted when their children paths are active:

```
<li className="headerNavLink"><IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="activeLink">introduction</IndexLink></li>
```

or

```
<li className="headerNavLink"><Link to="/" activeClassName="activeLink" onlyActiveOnIndex>introduction</Link></li>
```

Comment: for people who are using `react-router-bootstrap`, the equivalent component is `<IndexLinkContainer>`

Answer (score 11):

This changed again in v6.

The prop **exact** has been replaced with **end**.

```
<NavLink end to="/profile">
  Profile
</NavLink>
```

Here is the [React Router Dom docs reference](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.11.2/upgrading/v5#rename-navlink-exact-to-navlink-end)

Answer (score 1):

In react-router-dom ^4.0 **there's no IndexRoute or IndexLink**. Instead you need to specify the route path as **exact** and the child routes should be specified inside the `<Route>`'s component. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43311025/2713729