# Why can I not nest Route components in react-router 4.x?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

How in the world does one use nested routes in [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router), specifically, version 4.x? The following worked well in previous versions...

```
<Route path='/stuff' component={Stuff}>
  <Route path='/stuff/a' component={StuffA} />
</Route>
```

Upgrading to 4.x throws the following warning...

> Warning: You should not use <Route> component and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored

What in the heck is going on here? I've scoured [the docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/) for hours and can not successfully get nested routes working. How does one use `<Route>`*components* to nest their routes in react-router v4? How does my simplistic example translate to v4.x API compliance to nest a route?

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config

Isn't this example in the docs what you're looking for?

The `RouteWithSubRoutes` specifically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested routes with react router v4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Forget what you know about React Router < v4. You nest routes by literally nesting `<Routes>`. Check [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic). Specifically check out the Topics component. You don't declare your routes up front but instead dynamically when a component renders.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
)

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
          Rendering with React
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
          Components
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
          Props v. State
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    {/* NESTED ROUTES */}
    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
    <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
      <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
    )}/>
  </div>
)

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
)

export default BasicExample
```

Comment: Awesome thank you for a detailed answer. I'll get back to your tomorrow when I get as chance to check this out - but your example looks promising. I must say I am really disappointed with the api changes and will likely go without this library.

Comment: No worries. Give V4 a chance. It'll feel a little weird at first, but there's a very good reason the API was changed to this. It's much more powerful and is "just components".

Comment: I looked into this and it indeed works well. However, ran into more problems with my active class styling conflicting with children. After headdeaking for a good while, I started over with router5, which, comes with its own maddening baggage. Wish routing in react was stupid simple such as ui-router was in angular 1.x. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: @scniro Thanks for pointing out router5, looking into that now. React-router messed up on even breadcrumbs and other dependencies we had.

Comment: @TylerMcGinnis is it possible to nest a route like ```path={`${match.url}/:topicId/edit`}``` that will show a new page where you can edit the topic and which does not inherit layout from the `TopicId`?

Comment: react-router v4 is terrible.  It also couples your tests to the router . So even if your testing behavior that's not related to custom routes, your tests are forced to know about react-router as a dependency and you have to wrap your tests with MemoryRouter which is terrible.  Leaky as hell and your tests become even less isolated and coupled to this crap

Comment: that's a bad example let me update that.  I have another that does not have that check, same setup and still works

Answer (score 1):

With react-router **v4** and **v5** you can also use the `render` prop to nest routes

```
<Route 
  path='/stuff' 
  render={({ match: { url } }) => (
    <>
      <Route path={`${url}/`} component={Stuff} exact />
      <Route path={`${url}/a`} component={StuffA} />
    </>
  )} 
/>
```

In my opinion this syntax ends up more readable in most situations, compared to splitting out the sub-routes into a separately defined component passed in through the `component` prop.

I posted a [similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49321289/1082449) but noticed this question also has a lot of views and so thought it would be helpful to port it here.