# Nesting Routes in react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-routing, react-router-v4

I've upgraded the react router to version 4 in my application. But now I'm getting the error

```
Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored
```

What is wrong with this routing?

```
import {
    Switch,
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route, IndexRoute, Redirect,
    browserHistory
} from 'react-router-dom'   

render((
    <Router history={ browserHistory }>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={ Main }>
                <IndexRoute component={ Search } />
                <Route path='cars/:id' component={ Cars } />
                <Route path='vegetables/:id' component={ Vegetables } />
            </Route>
            <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('main'))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IndexRoute and browserHistory are not available in the latest version, also  Routes do not accept children Routes with v4, Instead, you can specify Routes within the component Itself

```
import {
    Switch,
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom'   

render((
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={ Main }/>

            <Redirect from='*' to='/' />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('main'))
```

Then in the Main Component

```
render() {
     const {match} = this.props;
     return (
        <div>
           {/* other things*/}
           <Route exact path="/" component={ Search } />
           <Route path={`${match.path}cars/:id`} component={ Cars } />
         </div>
    )

}
```

Similarly in the cars component

you will have

```
render() {
     const {match} = this.props;
     return (
        <div>
           {/* other things*/}
           <Route path={`${match.path}/vegetables/:id`} component={ Vegetables } />
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: Naked JS template literals are no longer allowed in JSX. Therefore you need to use something along these lines:

    <Route path={`${match.path}/vegetables/:id`} ... />

Comment: Be careful where you use exact when using nested routes. Exact will match only that exact path for example exact="/" doesn't match /posts/:id - this tripped me up a bit as a new user when trying to do a nested layout.

Answer (score 0):

Nested routes are not available from version react-router 4.x. Here is a [basic example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config) straight from react-router [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)  on how to code for nesting route secnarios in v4.x.

Also have a look on this question as well [Why can I not nest Route components in react-router 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845834/why-can-i-not-nest-route-components-in-react-router-4-x?rq=1)