# React Router 4.1.1 put header component in every other component w/o importing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to find documentation from the react router website https://reacttraining.com/react-router, and I cant seem to find a solution to have nested routes work in 4.1.1. For example in the older version of React Router, you would be able to nest Routes like so:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/cards" component={Example} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

This used the {this.props.children} and made it easy to have static components such as a navbar exist all through the application without having to import it in every component.

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                    <main>{ this.props.children }</main>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I have similar behavior with version 4.1.1. I do not want to import the header component all the time in the components.

I am using  at the moment, but it does not seem to accomplish what I am trying to do.

```
    <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App}>
                <Route path="/cards" component={Example} />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use nested Routes in react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452858/use-nested-routes-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In v4 it's much easier actually since `<Route />` is just normal component like any other. Instead of needing to use `props.children` you can put your routes exactly where you need the matching component to render. The following is equivalent to your v3 example:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <main>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/cards" component={Example} />
    </main>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</Router>
```

Updated answer to include an "index" path.

Comment: v3 and v4 differ in this respect. v4 doesn't really have the concept of a routes file. free your mind from a routes file and just remember that wherever your route is placed, is where the component will load as long the path matches.