# BrowserRouter doesnt accept child routes passed as props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am using react-router 4 with react-redux. but now I am not able to render any page. I am getting 404 while hitting URL. but console is not showing any error. may be I have colluded something with react-router version 3 but not able to get it what? one more thing here is that my one reducers is being called while store registration though I am not adding reducers in it.and more thing is IndexRoute deprecated in v4?

here is my config.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware,compose } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
//import rootReducer from './reducers'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './containers/App'
import promise from "redux-promise-middleware"
import logger from "redux-logger"
import {fetchUsers} from "./action/UserAction"
import {fetchChart} from "./action/ChartAction"
import {fetchNames} from "./action/SearchAction"
import reducer from "./reducers"
import routes from "./routes"

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger())
//const store= createStore(reducer,middleware)
const store= createStore(middleware)
//store.dispatch(fetchUsers());
//store.dispatch(fetchChart());
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter  routes={routes} />

  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

my routes.js

```
import App from "./pages/App"
import Users from "./pages/Users"
import Charts from "./pages/Charts"
import React from "react"
import { Route } from "react-router-dom"
export default (

  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    {/* <IndexRoute component={Users} /> */}
    <Route path="/" component={Users}/>
    <Route path="charts" name="charts" component={Charts}/>
  </Route>
);
```

my App.js

```
import {Link} from "react-router"
const App = () =>(

<div>
<h1> this is main page </h1>
<Link to="charts">charts</Link>
</div>
)

export default App
```

my charts.js

```
const Chart = () => (
    <h1> this is chart </h1>
)

export default Chart
```

my Users.js

```
const User = () =>(
    <div>
    <h1> this is user </h1>
    </div>
)

export default User
```

and reducer is that is being called

```
import  _intialState from "../api/names.js"
const intialValues = {names:['x','y','z','a','b','c','d','e','f'],
searchText:''}
export default function reducer(
    state=intialValues,
    action){
    console.log("search reducer",state)
    switch(action.type){
        case "SEARCH":{
         return Object.assign({},state,{searchText:action.payload})
        }
    default:
        return state;
    }

}
```

Comment: I did not see any prop named routes for BrowserRouter in documentation, This should work `<BrowserRouter  >{routes}</BrowserRouter>`

Comment: Indeed. thanks. I was searching here and there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [`react-router documentation`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter), there is no props called `routes` to `BrowserRouter`

Instead you can specify the routes to `BrowserRouter` as children.

> **children: node**
>
> A single child element to render.

Use it like

```
<BrowserRouter >
    {routes}
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: should we use index route in this?

Comment: IndexRoute is not available with React-router v4. See this answer for nesting routes in v4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452858/use-nested-routes-in-react-router-v4/44453559#44453559

Comment: ok..thanks now m getting my home page but not redirecting to other pages I think I should keep it in separete post