# IndexRoute equivalent in react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

```js
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/Project" component={Project}/>
  </div>
</Router>
)
```

how home component render in App component as a child (alternative 'IndexRoute')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify Child Routes in react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452858/specify-child-routes-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is just to move `Home` into the render() method of your app, like so:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Home />
        );
    }
}
```

Then, in your routes at the top, you could just have this:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/Project" component={Project}/>
  </div>
</Router>
```

However, it depends on what you want to do, exactly. Does the `App` always have `Home` as a child component? Otherwise, you can nest your inner component within the router like so:

This would set the props.children of the App to be the specific component that you are trying to use. That could be then used within your App like so:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <MyHeaderComponent />
            {this.props.children}
            <MyFooterComponent />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes App always  have Home as a  child component how to do so

Answer (score -1):

In the code below navigating to `/` will render `App` component with `Home` as its child

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route path="project" component={Project}/>
</Route>
```