# Sub routes not working in react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to nest routes in react router but `\sports\cricket` sub-routes like this aren't showing up. Following is the code:

**index.js**

```
const Root = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/sports" component={Sports} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

**sports.js**

```
return (
      <div>
        <Route path="cricket" component={Cricket} />
      </div>
    );
```

The console logs error 404 whenever I try to get `/sports/cricket`:

[image]

**Edit 1:** Moved the nested route inside of the `Sports`component.

Comment: What react-router version?

Comment: react router v4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify Child Routes in react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452858/specify-child-routes-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 0):

Nested routes don't work in v4. Assign subroutes in the component that the parent route points to. Like this:

**index.js**

```
const Root = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/sports" component={Sports}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

**sports.js**

```
return (
  <div>
    <Route path="/sports/cricket" component={Cricket} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Throws the same error in the console.

Comment: Instead of `BrowserRouter` replace it with `HashRouter` everywhere, and see if `localhost:3000/#/sports/cricket` works. The reason is that, if you havn't configured your routes on the server then you will get 404 not found on react browser routes.