# Routing Issue In ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a beginner in ReactJs. I am trying to create a multipage app, but I'm facing issues related to routing.

[image]

This is the code:

```react
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route} from 'react-router';

......

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={My}>
            <Route path="home" component={Home}>
               <Route path="contact" component={Contact}/>
               <Route path="about" component={About}/>
            </Route>
        </Route>

    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: which version of react-router are you using

Comment: @moazzam Why are you using React router when you want to create multipage app?

Comment: @madhurgarg if i am going towards wrong direction then can you please make my correction ? I visited different blogs and tutorials and they did something like this.

Comment: can you answer @Shubham's question? The version of your react-router.

Comment: With the errors that you are getting, I guess, you are using react-router v4. Refer this answer on how to configure your routes when you use nested routes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452858/specify-child-routes-in-react-router-v4/44453559#44453559

Comment: I don't know why you're using react-router for MPA. Assuming that you want to use react-router anyway I added my answer.

Comment: Can you please explain what's so surprising about using react router in this case @madhurgarg ?

Comment: @KristupasRepečka There is no need to use react-router in Multipage App.

Comment: @madhurgarg Your argument is meaningless unless you explain reasoning behind it. That's what react router is for - helping create single page applications with artificial routes which are convenient for user to bookmark and etc. SPA does not mean that the application should only have one route. Please.

Comment: @KristupasRepečka I am not saying SPA should have only one route. I am saying if you want to create multipage app, you don't need react-router, you can simply serve your html files using express server on frontend.

Comment: Since you asked, regardless of the merit of using routing in your case, it appears you need an actual TYPE of router. For instance, a `BrowserRouter` in v4 or older: `<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />`. There is no `history` yet which is why `location` does not exist either.

Comment: @madhurgarg But that's completely different thing. It is obvious author is not creating production webapp, rather he's learning reactjs :) Peace

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your React router is expecting a history prop that you haven't provided. Here is an example for Router v4 which doesn't support route nesting as in the question example.

```react
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

  ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className='App'>
        <div className='Page'>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={1} />
              <Route path="/second-page" component={2} />
              <Route path="/third-page" component={3} />
              <Route component={ErrorPage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

This one would route your components per their respective paths, or return an ErrorPage component if no routes were matched.

Edit: actually the history prop is useless and will be ignored in BrowserHistory, as the purpose of BrowserHistory is mostly to create a browserHistory.

from the source code :

```
warning(
     !this.props.history,
     '<BrowserRouter> ignores the history prop. To use a custom history, ' +
     'use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }`.'
)
```

Comment: Ignored by browserHistory, as the purpose of browserHistory is to create browserHistory. What do you mean with A is A and creates A?