# Dynimic child component rendering on same Layout Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a Component named `Layout` that should render different `child components` depending on the route. 
Parent component

```
export default class Layout extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <Navbar/>
                        {this.props.sidebar}
                        {this.props.content}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

In my `main.jxs` i want to render **3 Route** using the `Layout component` with different `ChildComponent` passed as sidebar and content props like:

```
<Route path="/profile" component={sidebar: <Sidebar />, content: <Content />} />
<Route path="/user" component={sidebar: <Sidebar />, content: <User />} />
<Route path="/edit" component={sidebar: <Sidebar />, content: <Edit />} />
```

Components are imported as well. In other words, i want to dynamically change the content of layout based on the route. How can i achieve this using `react-router-dom` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure nested Routes in react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452858/configure-nested-routes-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: How can this be a duplicate of that? No way! I'm trying to dynamically change the Layout children component based on the router. I'm **not** making a nested route.

Comment: You cannot pass props like that to the component, rather you can configure nested routes as you wish you app to look like

Comment: What's the result of the above code? it's kind of misleading.  you posted it as if it works.

Comment: @abdul It's not working. It's just what I want to achieve.
@ShubhamKhatri I don't want to render routes. I want to render component based on the route. Going to `/user` will update the `Layout component` to render `<Sidebar 7>` and `<User />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right you should use render func as prop in Route component (react router 4)
In order to can render a several components.
See `https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func`

Also I provide next small example

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/85086/

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, but you need define index route that will display layout and your other routes have to be child routes.

I am using this as

```
 <Route path="/" component={Layout} >
        <IndexRoute components={{ body: LandingPage }} />
        <Redirect from="appdetail/" to="/" />
        <Route path="appdetail/:applicationId" components={{ body: AppDetailPage }} />
 </Route>
```

than my Layout looks like:

```
export class Layout extends React.Component<ILayoutProps, void> {

    /**
     * Renders this object.
     *
     * @return  A JSX.Element.
     */
    public render(): JSX.Element {

        const mainDivStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            top: "0px",
            left: "0px",
            backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
            fontSize: "12px",
            fontFamily: "Gotham"
        };

        const contentDesktopStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
            height: "100%"
        };


        return (
            <div style={mainDivStyle}>
                    <div id="contentId" style={contentDesktopStyle}>
                        <Header />                        
                        { this.props.body }
                    </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't test your answer as it looked quite complicated and Arthur solution worked so sry but I gave him a thumb up although yours may surely work too.

Comment: Hi :-) 

No problem ... good is that you have some working solution :-)