# A Router may have only one child element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im try to learn react routing I created a project and in my index.js file i change my code as below

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './components/App';
import Signin from './components/Signin';
import Signup from './components/Signup';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router path="/">
        <Route path="/app" component={App} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />                                                                    
        <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
    </Router>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

but it gives an error like below

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in
>   'D:\REACT\react-crud\src'

Comment: Have you installed `react-router-dom`?

Comment: that means you need to install the `react-router-dom`, use this: `npm install --save react-router-dom`. Check this for more details: [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)

Comment: now it gives an error like `A <Router> may have only one child element`

Comment: @stewart wrap all the routes in a `div`, like this: `<Router><div> /*all routes*/ </div></Router>`

Comment: Just put all your routes between <div> </div> or <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install your package `react-router-dom` using `npm install -S react-router-dom` and also you can have `one child` for the Router. Wrap you Routes within a `div/`[`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch) whichever is suited to your needs

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
       <div>
        <Route path="/app" component={App} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />                                                                    
        <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
       </div>
    </Router>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: is it still have browserHistory package in react-route

Comment: No, browserHistory is not present in the latest version, however you can use BrowserRouter which behaves the same way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452858/nesting-routes-in-react-router-v4/44453559#44453559

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877828/react-js-not-redirect-firebase-auth-user can u help me with this

Comment: Checking your question