# Separate Log In page using HashRouter in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I would like to add a log in page that doesn't have App as a parent. This is my current HashRouter setup:

```
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <HashRouter>
      <App>
        <Route path='/path1' component={ Component1 } />
        <Route path='/path2' component={ Component2 } />
        <Route path='/path3' component={ Component3 } />
      </App>
    </HashRouter>
  </Provider>
```

If I do this:

```
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <HashRouter>
      <div>
        <Route path='/login' component={ Login } />
        <App>
          <Route path='/path1' component={ Component1 } />
          <Route path='/path2' component={ Component2 } />
          <Route path='/path3' component={ Component3 } />
        </App>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  </Provider>
```

Then I get the login page above the App. Here's my App Component:

```
const App = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <Navbar/>
    <div className='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1'>
      { children }
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

What's the best way to get a login path with a Login component, that doesn't include the App?

Comment: Why don't you add a subpath for `App`? e.g. `/session`. You could also just use `App` in every component instead of using it as a parent. There is no "best way". There are many many solutions.

Comment: I wouldn't want `/session` in the url of every page, that would be aesthetically unpleasing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using react-router v4, you need to put your nested routes inside the parent component instead of nesting routes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4#answer-43311025) for the explanation.

In your case, the simplest approach would be something like this.

```
<Provider store={ store }>
  <HashRouter>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/login' component={ Login } />
        <Route path='/' component={ App } />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </HashRouter>
</Provider>

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Navbar/>
    <div className='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1'>
      <Route path='/path1' component={ Component1 } />
      <Route path='/path2' component={ Component2 } />
      <Route path='/path3' component={ Component3 } />
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Notice that how I have used [`<Switch>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) to wrap the `'/login'` and `'/'` routes. This will make sure that it only renders the first matching route from the given routes according to given order. So when the path is `'/login'`, it will only render `Login` page even though it also matches(not exact match, you need to use ['exact' attribute](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) for an exact match) the `'/'` route.

**Update:**

Above method is the recommended approach in react-router documentation. But if you see a value in keeping all your routes in one place, you can still use `<Switch>` with what you already have.

```
<Provider store={ store }>
  <HashRouter>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/login' component={ Login } />
        <App>
          <Route path='/path1' component={ Component1 } />
          <Route path='/path2' component={ Component2 } />
          <Route path='/path3' component={ Component3 } />
        </App>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </HashRouter>
</Provider>
```

Comment: I knew about `exact path` but not `<Switch>`. Thank you for this answer. I do think there are merits to having a big Router with all your routes in it - it serves to show you what all your routes are. If I wanted to nest my other paths inside my `<HashRouter>` how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use different layouts with a very basic main layout.

routes.js

```
export default () => (
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <Route component={WebLayout}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        </Route>
        <Route component={AppLayout}>
            <Route path="account" component={Account} />
        </Route>
        <Route component={SecurityLayout}>
            <Route path="login" component={Login} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
);
```

layout.js

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => (
    <div>
        {children}
    </div>
);
```

applayout.js

```
const AppLayout = ({ children }) => (
    ...
);
```

securitylayout.js

```
const SecurityLayout = ({ children }) => (
    ...
);
```