# How to do nested routes with react router 4?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Does anyone know how to do nested routes in react router 4? I want to set up routes like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';

import Containers from './containers/index';
import Components from './components/index';

export default (
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/users' component={Containers.Users} />
      <Route path='/users/:id' component={Containers.User} />
    </Switch>
)
```

But `/tickets/:id` continues to default to the component that `Containers.Users` renders -- not the one from `Containers.User`. I had everything working with react-router 3 with a very simple setup but it seems that a lot has changed:

```
<Route path="/users" component={Containers.Users}>
  <Route path="/users/:id" component={Containers.User}/>
</Route >
```

Does anyone know the latest set up for a very simple nested route pattern like the above for react-router 4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested routes with react router v4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)

Comment: You can see this [real app example](https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/budgeting-sample-app-webpack2) where React Router 4 is implemented properly with nested routes

Answer (score 1):

Now in v4 you should add the Routes in the parent component, no more nested routes.

```
    <Redirect from="/courses/" to="/courses/html" />
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/courses/html" component={HTML} />
        <Route path="/courses/css" component={CSS} />
        <Route path="/courses/javascript" component={JavaScript} />
    </Switch>
```

Found this here https://teamtreehouse.com/community/warning-you-should-not-use-route-component-and-route-children-in-the-same-route-route-children-will-be-ignored

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem earlier today with React Router v4 and this solved the issue for me

```
<Route exact path="/users" component={Containers.Users/>
<Route path="/users/:id" component={Containers.Users />
```

In this case `/users` is the base path for your route with `/users/:id` being a child path so you need to specify an exact path for the parent route.