# How to pass in children to parent <Route> component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'd like to define the following structure on my page:

[image]

Where **layout** is static and contains elements that appear on every page, and render **page content** based on the URL.

To achieve this I've defined `AppRoutes`, `Layout`, `About` and `NotFound` and used `react-router`, `v4`:

AppRoutes.js

```
export default class AppRoutes extends React.Component
{  
    render ()
    {
        const supportsHistory = 'pushState' in window.history;
        return (
        <BrowserRouter forceRefresh={!supportsHistory} history={hashHistory} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
            <div>
                <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
                    <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
                    <Route path='*' component={PageNotFround}/>
                </Route>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>);
    };
};
```

Layout.js

```
class NaviGationPane extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default class Layout extends React.Component
{
    render ()
    {
        return (
        <div className="app-container">
            <header>
                <NaviGationPane/>
            </header>
            <div className="app-content">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Layout's header is rendered, but at `/` or at `/about` the *page content* is empty.
If I change it to the one below the `PageNotFound` is rendered always at the end, no matter what is the path, while the rest works as I expected, namely `/` renders he `Layout`, while `/about` renders the `About` component.

```
<BrowserRouter forceRefresh={!supportsHistory} history={hashHistory} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}>
                <div>
                    <Route path='/' component={Layout}/>
                    <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
                    <Route path='*' component={PageNotFround}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
```

I checked that in both cases `this.props.children` in `Layout` is undefined.

**UPDATE**
I tried out a few things and figured that

```
 <Layout>
     <Switch>
         <Route exact path='/' component={IndexPage}/>
         <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
         <Route component={PageNotFround}/>
      </Switch>
 </Layout>
```

will be the basic scenario and now I understand why my previous code did not work: in `react-router` v4 the

```
<Route to='/' component={Layout}>
       <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
</Route>
```

is not valid. The structure

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <div>
         <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
         <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
         <Route path='*' component={PageNotFround}/>
      </div>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

will keep matching routes until all rules are exhausted, the `/` will be matched every time and `*` will also be matched every time.

So I use the `<Layout>` component to wrap everything and create the routes inside and to ensure that only one path is matched I use the `<Switch>`.

This is not what I wanted, because if I add a path `/about/:user` only the `About` component will be rendered. So the question is still open.

Comment: the code looks good, I think it can be a problem connected with version 4. Look at this topic: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3928

Comment: I got some useful information from it but it is not really the answer, as my update says.

Comment: ```<Layout><ComponentToRenderOnAllPages /><Switch>...</Switch></Layout>```

Comment: @ReiDien, this is exactly what I wrote under the **UPDATE** part. My question is how to add routes `/about` and `/about/:user` as a single entry in the switch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested routes with react router v4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)

Comment: I found the explanation at https://egghead.io/lessons/react-render-nested-routes-with-react-router-v4. In short routes can be nested in components