# React Router v4 Nested Routes with Switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Trying to do the following, but it's not working.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div className="route-wrapper">
      <Switch>
        <App>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/user" component={UserPage} />
        </App>
        <Route component={Err404} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('main')
)
```

As the documentation says only Route and Redirect elements are allowed inside a Switch element. How do I get this to work without explicitly wrapping HomePage and UserPage in App or having the error page wrapped by App?

Comment: What's stopping you from wrapping the <Switch> with the <App> component?

Comment: The App component contains the header, navbar and whatever content is in the route. I don't want the header and navbar to be there on the 404 page.

Comment: then I would use a <Route component={App} /> for displaying your App part and inside the App, you can do the routing between home page and user page. that's the v4 way of doing this

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While I have begun developing a "Universal React app", where the first page load is done with server-side rendering, I faced similar problem as the React-Router had just updated to 4.0. You should consider restructuring you application something as given below:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div className="route-wrapper">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
        <Route component={Err404} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('main')
)
```

Where the App component is refactored as following:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route exact path="/user" component={UserPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding this example: Is it even possible to reach the Err404 component? The first Route matches everything and loads the App component, in which case would the Err404 component loaded? It does not detect if no match was found in subsequent Switches, does it?

Comment: Agreed. I don't think this will work - the Err404 component will never render.

Comment: This looks like a potential solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4

Comment: can i use `<switch>` with `<Route>` inside functional component, how to use?