# React router, <Switch> structure

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I have a React component `App` which is a child of `<Router>`. Within `App`, I am rendering different Components based on the url path using `<Switch>` and `<Route>` components.

I know that the role of `<Switch>` is to render (only) the first matching `<Route>` component.

My `App`'s render function looks like this.

```
return (
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/somepath' component={SomeComponent} />
        <Route path='/someotherpath' component={SomeOtherComponent} />
        <Main>
            <Route path='/anotherpath' component={AnotherComponent} />
            <Route component={DefaultComponent} />
        </Main>
    </Switch>
);
```

The problem I faced was that when I am rendering `AnotherComponent`, `DefaultComponent` is also being rendered.

For now, it seems that wrapping the routes in `<Main>` into another `<Switch>` component will enforce the switch behavior. For example,

```
<Main>
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/anotherpath' component={AnotherComponent} />
        <Route component={DefaultComponent} />
    </Switch>
</Main>
```

So, is it a good practice to nest `<Switch>` components as I did? Is there a more elegant approach to achieve this?

Comment: @iamcaleberic it is perfectly fine to have unconditional Route in a Switch. It is the fallback in case none of the previous Route matched.

Comment: @jun-park `Switch` only manages its direct `Route` (or `Redirect`) children. You can refer to this question that exposes the same problem as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830068/react-router-v4-nested-routes-with-switch. Considering your question about good practices, I guess there is no problem with nested `Switch`.

Comment: @iamcaleberic in these examples from the docs, the fallback Route of the Switch does not have a defined path prop: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch, https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match

Comment: @PierreKraemer seen that thanks for the correction