# Nested Switch does not work in React router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have two components that both have a switch element like so:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Router>
        <AppBar position="static" color="inherit">
          <Toolbar>
            <Button color="inherit"><Link to="/deployments">Deployments</Link></Button>
            <Button color="inherit"><Link to="/tasks">Tasks</Link></Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/tasks" component={TasksPage}>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function TasksPage({match}) {
    return (
        <div className="DeploymentsPage">
          {loading ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : 
          <div>
            <h1>Available Tasks</h1>
            <ul>
              {tasks.map((el, i) => <li key={i}><Link to={`${match.path}/${el.id}`}>{el.id}</Link></li>)}
            </ul>
            </div>
          }
         <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/tasks/:id" component={TaskPage} />
         </Switch> 
        </div>
    );
}
```

If I go to `/tasks/1` now, the TaskPage is not shown! Whereas if I move the exact same Route element into the Switch of `App` it works just fine.

Why is that? I tried to follow this tutorial: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: You are adding `exact` to both paths. `/tasks/1` is not exact with `/tasks`

Comment: I think Miller is right, how do you expect `/tasks/1` to render if you said that route should only render if it `exact`ly matches `/tasks`?

Comment: But /tasks/1 is exact to /tasks/:id, is it not? /tasks/1 does not render TaskPage but /tasks renders TasksPage (bad naming I know)

Comment: It will never get to that point as TasksPage won't render

Comment: Ooh yes I get it now. TaskPage only renders if TasksPage is rendered. And since both routes never exactly match it is not shown

Comment: try to rmove exact in the           <Route exact path="/tasks/:id" component={TaskPage} />

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To add more information about @Miller comment, because you add `exact` to your main Route (`/tasks`), your nested Route (`/tasks/:id`) can never be reached.

Example : If you attempt to have **exactly** `/tasks`, you can't hit this route with `/tasks/1`.

See how `exact` works [here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool)

It should work without the `exact` on your main Route.

Similar example of what you want to achieve : https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/route-config

Answer (score -3):

I think you are misunderstanding the concept of Switch statements and Routes. ( https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start )

Nevertheless, you should declare all your routes directly into App.js, for instance. And, if you want to redirect the user for certain route, just use NavLink. Moreover, you cannot nest Switches!!! You might as well just nest Routes.

Thus, this might be the reason for all your troubles. Try creating a nested Route instead.

This link might help you better in the visual part:

[React Router v4 Nested Routes with Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830068/react-router-v4-nested-routes-with-switch)

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6199 << supreme!

Comment: You don't have to declare your Routes or Switches in one place actually, this is one of the selling points of "declarative routing"

Comment: He can definitely do a switch inside a switch.