# nested route for one component reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am new in reactJs, i was trying to do nested route for one component and it's not working
following way i was trying to do nested and error occur like this

> Warning: You should not use  and  in the same route;  will be ignored

```
render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route exact path="/test" component={App}/>
            <Route  path="/register" component={Registration}>
                <Route path="/register/pet/more" component={App}/>
            </Route>
        </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root'))
```

So what should i have to do for nested route for one component.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid nested routes and instead use a combination of `Switch` and `exact` in `react-router-dom`. Here's how it can be done.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    <Route exact path="/test" component={App}/>
    <Route exact path="/register" component={Registration} />
    <Route exact path="/register/pet/more" component={App} />
</Switch>
```

The idea is that `Switch` selects only the matching route, and `exact` does an exact match, so this should solve your problem.

Comment: `<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    <Route exact path="/test" component={App}/>
    <Route exact path="/register" component={Registration} />
    <Route exact path="/register/pet/more" component={Registration} />
</Switch>` Can i route one component with two path as like above code?

Comment: Yes, you can. Switch will choose the route that exactly matches the path defined.

Comment: It's a good practice to upvote answers that solve your problem, as it motivates better answers.

Answer (score 1):

what version of react-router are you using? If you are using React-router  version 4 you put your nested route in another component.see the link below
[Nested routes with react router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)