# You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

I'm trying to set up react-router in an example application, and I'm getting the following error:

```
You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>
```

My app is set up like so:

#### Parent component

```jsx
const router = (
  <div className="sans-serif">
    <Router histpry={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Main}>
        <IndexRoute component={PhotoGrid}></IndexRoute>
        <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </div>
);

render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

#### Child/`Main` component

```jsx
export default () => (
  <div>
    <h1>
      <Link to="/">Redux example</Link>
    </h1>
  </div>
)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

[Here's a Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/zwvjpx4pjx) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Kindly mention  which version you are using of `react-router`, Because you are using different approaches for the Index Routing.

Comment: I got this message due to a failure of hot reloading after updating some app dependencies. A manual quit and restart of the development server solved the issue. Just FYI in case someone else has the message pop up out of nowhere.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using React-Router V4, as you used the same in the original [Sandbox Link.](https://codesandbox.io/s/zwvjpx4pjx)

You are rendering the `Main` component in the call to `ReactDOM.render` that renders a `Link` and Main component is outside of `Router`, that's why it is throwing the error:

> You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

**Changes**:

1. Use any one of **[these Routers](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router)**, BrowserRouter/HashRouter etc..., because you are using React-Router V4.
2. Router can have only one child, so wrap all the routes in a `div` or [Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch).
3. React-Router V4, doesn't have the concept of nested routes, if you wants to use nested routes then define those routes directly inside that component.

---

Check **[this working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/qvv3qo5vyw)** with each of these changes.

#### Parent Component:

```
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="sans-serif">
      <Route path="/" component={Main} />
      <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

#### `Main` component from route

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default () => (
  <div>
    <h1>
      <Link to="/">Redux example</Link>
    </h1>
  </div>
)
```

Etc.

---

Also check this answer: [Nested routes with react router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 149):

**For [JEST](https://jestjs.io/) users**

if you use Jest for testing and this error happen just wrap your component with `<BrowserRouter>`

```
describe('Test suits for MyComponentWithLink', () => {
it('should match with snapshot', () => {
const tree = renderer
  .create(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <MyComponentWithLink/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
  .toJSON();
 expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
 });
});
```

Comment: This answer uses `react-test-renderer`, which is not built in for create-react-app. If you use the built in `@testing-library/react`, use `render(<BrowserRouter><MyComponent/></BrowserRouter>);` instead.

Comment: Wrap it in `<MemoryRouter>` instead of `<BrowserRouter>` because `<MemoryRouter>` is lighter weight.

Comment: A savior if the day!

Comment: This worked great with Storybook too.

Comment: How do I access `MyComponentWithLink` if I want to use features like jest.spyOn on the rendered instance?

Answer (score 23):

Enclose Link component inside BrowserRouter component

```
 export default () => (
  <div>
   <h1>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/">Redux example</Link>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </h1>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 17):

Whenever you try to show a `Link` on a page thats outside the `BrowserRouter` you will get that error.

This error message is essentially saying that any component that is not a child of our `<Router>` cannot contain any React Router related components.

You need to migrate your component hierarchy to how you see it in the first answer above. For anyone else reviewing this post who may need to look at more examples.

Let's say you have a `Header.js`component that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className="ui secondary pointing menu">
            <Link to="/" className="item">
                Streamy
            </Link>
            <div className="right menu">
                <Link to="/" className="item">
                    All Streams
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

And your `App.js` file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import StreamCreate from './streams/StreamCreate';
import StreamEdit from './streams/StreamEdit';
import StreamDelete from './streams/StreamDelete';
import StreamList from './streams/StreamList';
import StreamShow from './streams/StreamShow';
import Header from './Header';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <Header />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
        <Route path="/" exact component={StreamList} />
        <Route path="/streams/new" exact component={StreamCreate} />
        <Route path="/streams/edit" exact component={StreamEdit} />
        <Route path="/streams/delete" exact component={StreamDelete} />
        <Route path="/streams/show" exact component={StreamShow} />
        </div> 
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Notice that the `Header.js` component is making use of the `Link` tag from `react-router-dom` but the componet was placed outside the `<BrowserRouter>`, this will lead to the same error as the one experience by the OP. In this case, you can make the correction in one move:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import StreamCreate from './streams/StreamCreate';
import StreamEdit from './streams/StreamEdit';
import StreamDelete from './streams/StreamDelete';
import StreamList from './streams/StreamList';
import StreamShow from './streams/StreamShow';
import Header from './Header';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
        <Header />
        <Route path="/" exact component={StreamList} />
        <Route path="/streams/new" exact component={StreamCreate} />
        <Route path="/streams/edit" exact component={StreamEdit} />
        <Route path="/streams/delete" exact component={StreamDelete} />
        <Route path="/streams/show" exact component={StreamShow} />
        </div> 
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Please review carefully and ensure you have the `<Header />` or whatever your component may be inside of not only the `<BrowserRouter>` but also inside of the `<div>`, otherwise you will also get the error that a Router may only have one child which is referring to the `<div>` which is the child of `<BrowserRouter>`. Everything else such as `Route` and components must go within it in the hierarchy.

So now the `<Header />` is a child of the `<BrowserRouter>` within the `<div>` tags and it can successfully make use of the `Link` element.

Answer (score 5):

Make it simple:

```
render(<BrowserRouter><Main /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and don't forget: `import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";`

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error because I was importing a reusable component from an npm library and the versions of `react-router-dom` did not match.

So make sure you use the same version in both places!

Comment: In my case I was using pnpm to develop a library and a sample app in the same repo. Both projects have their own package.json but webpack sees two different libraries. The solution is to link them: ` "react-router-dom": "link:../main/node_modules/react-router-dom",` so that both library and application are using the same react router.

Answer (score 3):

I kinda come up with this code :

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

// import componentns
import Main from './components/Main';
import PhotoGrid from './components/PhotoGrid';
import Single from './components/Single';

// import react router
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, BrowserRouter, browserHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

class MainComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
          <Route path="/" component={Main} >
            <IndexRoute component={PhotoGrid}></IndexRoute>
            <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}></Route>
          </Route>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<MainComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I think the error was because you were rendering the `Main` component, and the `Main` component didn't know anything about `Router`, so you have to render its father component.

Answer (score 2):

add this to your index.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
```

and then wrap your `<App />` within the `<Router></Router>` to use links within your react application.

like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <App/>
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to create another component that just uses the BrowserRouter from "react-router-dom" and wrap your component with the Link inside it.

```
const ReduxExample () => (
  <div>
    <h1>
      <Link to="/">Redux example</Link>
    </h1>
  </div>
)
```

then you can do this

```
const NewReduxExample = () => {
   <BrowserRouter>
     <ReduxExample />
   </BrowserRouter>
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do this in your index.js file in your src folder.

`import React from 'react';`
`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`
`import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';`

`import App from './App';`

`ReactDOM.render(<Router><App /></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));`

Then in your Component.jsx file you can import Link

`import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';`

and use the Link like so without a Router/Route tag.

`<Link to="/">Page</Link>`

Answer (score 1):

wrap every component inside BrowserRouter where you're calling reactDom.render like this

```
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(

  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write **router** in place of **Main** in **render** (last line in the code).
Like this
ReactDOM.render(router, document.getElementById('root'));

Answer (score 0):

You can put the Link component inside the Router componet. Something like this:

```
 <Router>
     <Route path='/complete-profiles' component={Profiles} />
     <Link to='/complete-profiles'>
         <div>Completed Profiles</div>
     </Link>
 </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

I base my answer on this [article](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/). Here's a simple solution.

```
// index.test.tsx
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import Login from ".";

it("should display Login", () => {
  const history = createBrowserHistory();
  render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Login />
    </Router>
  );
  const linkElement = screen.getByText(/Login/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I use react testing library that comes with create-react-app. I know is simpler solution to what you asked, but I was missing the imports in the other answers so I just put it altogether.
Here is the test file:

```
// HomePage.test.js 
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './HomePage';

it('Homepage contains heading 1', () => {
  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <HomePage />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

  screen.getByRole('heading', { level: 1 });
});

it('Homepage contains link', () => {
  render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <HomePage />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

  expect(screen.getByRole('link')).toHaveAttribute('href', '/articles');
});
```

The main component that I would be testing would look like this

```
// HomePage.js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Welcome to React page</h1>
      <p>
        Click on <Link to='/articles'>Articles</Link> to see what is shared
        today
      </p>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a similar manner as one of the previous answers, this was my solution to using this in an npm-package which uses Storybook for development:

```
//preview.js
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

export const decorators = [
  (Story) => {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Story />
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
]
```

Answer (score -12):

If you don't want to change much, use below code inside onClick()method.

```
this.props.history.push('/');
```