# You should not use Link outside a Router using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am trying to do routing using react-router-dom. I got an error like you should not use  outside the  like this.Here below i am attaching my code please check.

**index.js**

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import App from './containers/App';




render(
  <Provider>
     <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**App.js**

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import Dropdown from './dropdown';
import './styles.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import Addatttemp from './Addatttemp';

const options = [
    {label: 'One' },
    {label: 'Two'},
    {label: 'Three'},
    {label: 'Four' }
]
const AgentValues=[
    {label: 'Add Att/temp', value:'Addatttemp' },
    {label: 'Mod prof LVL',value:'Modproflvl'},
    {label: 'Override Attr',value:'Overrideattr'},
    {label: 'Temp',value:'temp'}
]
const defaultOption = options[0]
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="navbar">
                    <div className="align">
                        <div className="dropdown">
                            <Dropdown options={AgentValues} name='Agent'/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="dropdown">
                            <Dropdown options={options} name='Templete'/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="dropdown">
                            <Dropdown options={options} name='Report'/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="dropdown">
                            <Dropdown options={options} name='Search'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path='/Agent/Addatttemp' component={Addatttemp} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Dropdown.js**

```jsx
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class dropdown extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        var dropdownList = []
        this.props.options.map((res)=>{
            dropdownList.push(<Link to={'/'}>{res.label}</Link>)
        })
        return(
            <div>
                <button className="dropbtn"><Link to={'/'}>{this.props.name}</Link>
                </button>
                <div className="dropdown-content">
                    {dropdownList}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default dropdown;
```

**Home.js**

```jsx
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome to the Tornadoes Website!</h1>
    </div>
)

export default Home
```

**Addatttemp.js**

```jsx
import React from 'react'

const AddTemp = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome to the Add att/temp!</h1>
    </div>
)

export default AddTemp
```

Like this i wrote my code, but when i run this code it throws me the error like **Uncaught Error: You should not use Link outside a Router** . I am unable to resolve this, please give me suggestions that what i did wrong in it, Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have forgotten to use `Router` at all other than importing it `BrowserRouter as Router`. Do you use a linter? It should warn you about unused variables.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks for the reply, Can you please elaborate it and please check my code and give me suggestions that where i did wrong

Comment: I following the error message suggest you to use `Router` :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640280/you-should-not-use-link-outside-a-router)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says you are not having `Router` up the component tree.

You could use it in `App` component like this

```jsx
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
              <div>
            <div className="navbar">
                <div className="align">
                    <div className="dropdown">
                        <Dropdown options={AgentValues} name='Agent'/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="dropdown">
                        <Dropdown options={options} name='Templete'/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="dropdown">
                        <Dropdown options={options} name='Report'/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="dropdown">
                        <Dropdown options={options} name='Search'/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/Agent/Addatttemp' component={Addatttemp} />
            </Switch>
            </div>
          </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

**Also**

You don't need constructor that just calls `super`

```jsx
// this is noop
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
}
```

You don't need to push to external array when using `map`.

```jsx
var dropdownList = this.props.options.map(res => (
   <Link to={'/'}>{res.label}</Link>
))
```

Comment: Thank for reply, As per your suggestion i added the Router above the switch in App.js, but same error i am getting.  And i wrote the map for drop down list in dropdown.js file

Comment: @HussianShaik Not "above the switch" but above all the content including header w/ dropdowns. All router related components including (`Link`, `Switch` etc) require `router` prop to be provided via `context`. So you need to put some `Router` (that populates context w/ `router`) somewhere up the component tree.

Comment: can you please guide me that in my code where should i do that. i am struggling with it.

Comment: @HussianShaik I've posted almost complete code. You need to read some basic react tutorial to begin with.

Comment: @HussianShaik Also read this https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show a `Link` on a page or any element outside of `BrowserRouter` you are going to get this error. This error message is saying that any component that is not a child of a router cannot contain any `react-router-dom` related components.

What you need to learn for effective development in React is your component hierarchy.

In your case your parent component, the one at the top of the hierarchy is `App`, how do I know? because you said so right here in your `index.js` file:

```
render(
  <Provider>
     <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

So, when working with `react-router-dom`, next up on that hierarchy chart should be your `BrowserRouter`. This is where you start to lose me and React as we are both looking for `BrowserRouter` inside your `App` component and do not see it.

This is what we should be seeing right now:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/Agent/Addatttemp" exact component={Addattemp} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Notice I am using the `exact` keyword? I am using the `exact` keyword so I don’t accidentally match one of these other routes I am about to implement.

So please go ahead and add your `BrowserRouter` or in your case, your `Router` which is acting as `BrowserRouter` higher up on that hierarchy below `App`, it has to be next up in the hierarchy, everything else is a child of that `BrowserRouter` and must go within it.

And since you are never going to make use of the `Link` from `react-router-dom` inside your `App` component, go ahead and clean it up like so:

`import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";`

Once you follow the above, that error should go away.