# Using React Router to load components You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi I am using React Router to load components. It keeps giving me an error saying

> You should not use `<Link>` outside a `<Router>`

When the user first goes to the page, I want them to go to the login page. After the login is successful and the homepage loads, I have a Navbar component on the homepage. How can I nest the routes? I am having trouble please help.

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Landing from "./components/Landing";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Course from "./components/AddCourse";
import Homepage from "./components/Homepage";
import AddCourse from "./components/AddCourse";
import SearchCourse from "./components/SearchCourse";
import SearchItem from "./components/SearchItem";
import Profile from "./components/Profile";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact={true} />
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} exact={true} />
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/homepage" component={Homepage} exact={true} />
              <Route path="/" component={SearchCourse} exact={true} />
              <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} exact={true} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

navbar

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.usertoken;
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    this.setState({
      name: decoded.name,
      email: decoded.email
    });
  }
  logOut(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    localStorage.removeItem("usertoken");
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul style={navBarStyle} id="sidenav-1" className="sidenav sidenav-fixed">
        <li>
          <img style={imageStyle} src="" alt="Avatar" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/profile">
            <i style={linkStyle} class="material-icons ">
              person
            </i>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/MaterializeCSS" target="_blank">
            <i style={linkStyle} class="material-icons ">
              book
            </i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/searchCourses">
            <i style={linkStyle} class="material-icons">
              search
            </i>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li style={linkStyle}>
          <a href="" onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)}>
            <i style={linkStyles} class="fas fa-sign-out-alt" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

homepage

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import CourseItem from "./CourseItem";

class Homepage extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "Dashboard";
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container">
          <div>
            <h3>Dashboard</h3>
            <hr />
          </div>
          <div className="col" />
          {/* {this.props.children} */}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Homepage;
```

Comment: I don't see where you export `Navbar`. You should `export default withRouter(Navbar)` in there

Comment: i did that doesnt fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640280/you-should-not-use-link-outside-a-router)

Comment: Can you share your ReactDOM.render(??, document.getElementById(??)); Section?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the file index.js and take your `<App />` tag inside a group 
`<BrowserRouter> </BrowserRouter>`. Then you will be able to use Link, Route and Switch without problem

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```