# Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to create a router in my react app and it shows this error, I tried with out link and using Navlink but it doesn't work.

App.js`:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Rute from "./components/Rute";
import BottomNavigation from "@material-ui/core/BottomNavigation";
import BottomNavigationAction from "@material-ui/core/BottomNavigationAction";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("recents");

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <BottomNavigation value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
        <Link to="/">
          <BottomNavigationAction label="acasa" value="acasa" />
        </Link>
        <Link to="/harta">
          <BottomNavigationAction label="harta" value="harta" />
        </Link>
        <Link to="/lista">
          <BottomNavigationAction label="lista" value="lista" />
        </Link>
      </BottomNavigation>
      <Rute />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Please include `Rute.js` import statement for further clarification

Comment: `import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../screns/Home';
import Lista from '../screns/Lista';
import Harta from '../screns/Harta';`

Comment: check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640280/you-should-not-use-link-outside-a-router

Comment: I watched but doesn't work

Comment: Link component must be inside BrowserRouter

Comment: Can you show me what the code looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link component must be inside BrowserRouter, you can make the following change in the return.

```
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Rute>
      <BottomNavigation value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
        <Link to="/">
          <BottomNavigationAction label="acasa" value="acasa" />
        </Link>
        <Link to="/harta">        <BottomNavigationAction label="harta" value="harta" />
        </Link>
        <Link to="/lista">        <BottomNavigationAction label="lista" value="lista" />
        </Link>
      </BottomNavigation>
      </Rute>
    </React.Fragment>

  );
```