# Unable to access App component when using React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to make my application more route driven/controlled. I am using `React Router` and an external Routes file in order to abstract the route logic out of my components. The other routes and components are working properly except for the App component itself. I am essentially trying to wrap all of the other routes under the root route (`'/'`) who's component is `App.js`.

Below is my `routes/index.js` file.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Router, Route, Redirect  } from "react-router";

import App from "../App.js";
import Home from "../components/Home/Home";
import Games from "../components/Games/containers/Games";
import LoginSignUp from "../components/LoginSignUp/LoginSignUp";
import NotFound from "../components/NotFound/NotFound";
import Account from "../components/Account/Account";
import Trivia from "../components/Trivia/Trivia";
import store from '../config/store';

const getGame = (nextState, replace, callback) => {
    var userGames = store.getState().auth.user.games;
    if (userGames.includes(parseInt(nextState.match.params.id))){
        return <Trivia/>
    } else {
        return <Redirect to="/404"/>
   }
};

const Routes = ({ history, store }) => {

    return (
         <Router history={history} store={store}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <Route exact path="/404" component={NotFound} />
                <Route exact path="/give/different/path" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/games" component={Games}/>
                <Route path="/account" component={Account}/>
                <Route path="/games/:id" render={getGame}/>
                <Route path='/login' component={LoginSignUp}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    );
};

Routes.propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Routes;
```

I have also tried this route setup without `<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>` and I've tried using `<Route exact path="/" component={App}>` to no avail.

Below is my `App.js` component.

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header/Header.js';
import './App.css';
import {createAction} from "redux-actions";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        loggedIn: true
    }

    render(){
         debugger
         return (
             <div className="App">
                 <Header loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} user={this.props.user}/>
             </div>
         );
     }
 }

 const mapStateToProps = ({games, auth}) => {
    return{
        user: auth.user,
        games: games.games
    }
 };

 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getGame(obj) {
            const actionCreator = createAction(
                "games/getGame"
            );
            const action = actionCreator(obj);
            dispatch(action);
        }
    }
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Here are my related dependencies and their versions.

```
"react-router": "^5.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.0",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the insight provided by the other answers, I was able to come up with a solution to satisfy all of my needs.

Here are my updated files. The first is my root `index` file. As a precaution, I replaced all instances of `import {Router} from 'react-router'` with `import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'` which was suggested by [this issue's answer](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6679). Replacing all instances of `react-router` with `react-router-dom` helped stop the `You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>` or `You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>` errors.

```
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} store={store}>
            <App/>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
```

My routes/index.

```
const Routes = ({ history, store }) => {

    return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/404" component={NotFound} />
                <Route exact path="/games" component={Games} />
                <Route exact path="/account" render={accountDetails}/>
                <Route path="/games/:id" render={getGame} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginSignUp} />
                <Redirect to='404' />
            </Switch>
    );
};
```

And App now includes the below.

```
import Routes from './routes/index.js';

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        loggedIn: true
    };

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Header/>
                <Routes/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

First, I decided to take `App` out of `routes/index`. I based my original route hierarchy based on another project that was not using `react-router 4`. That's why in the other project the nested routes under `App`'s route was achieving what I was trying to. In `react router 4` [this was not possible](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640280/you-should-not-use-link-outside-a-router), hence the `Cannot use Link outside of Router` error. So instead, I wrapped `App` in the `Router` in my root index file, then wrapped all other routes in a `Switch` in my `routes/index` file and imported them into `App`. `App` can now utilize Router for the `Header` component as well as for the other routes wrapped in the `Switch`.

This also solved my issue for having to sacrifice `exact path` for `App`. Since I wanted to use the `Header` on every page I wanted `App` to be on every page. Using `exact path` prevented me from doing this. It also prevented me from using '/' to render `Home`. When I made `App`'s `exact path` to just `path`, I was able to accomplish this, but any random undeclared route could be put in. For example, `localhost:3000/poop` would not render `NotFound` as I intended, it would just render nothing.

In summary, by moving `App` out of `routes/index` it allowed me to wrap it directory in `Router` in the root index file. Then by importing `Routes` into `App` I was able to allow my app to be more route driven while maintaining the `Header` across all pages. Also, by wrapping all of my routes in a `Switch` and having the root path be an `exact path`, I could properly handle unknown paths and render the `NotFound` component by using `<Redirect to='404' />`.

Answer (score 0):

It wont work like that, look that you have a path `/` for `App` and then `/` for `Home`, it can't match properly. Please review the React Router docs. Here is the link to the [nested routes](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy/nested-routes) example.

To have you going somewhere look at this modification to your Router
You have:

```
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <Route exact path="/404" component={NotFound} />
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/games" component={Games}/>
                <Route path="/account" component={Account}/>
                <Route path="/games/:id" render={getGame}/>
                <Route path='/login' component={LoginSignUp}/>
            </Route>
```

but will work better

```
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/account" component={Account}/>
            <Route exact path="/games" component={Games}/>
            <Route exact path="/games/:id" render={getGame}/>
            <Route exact path='/login' component={LoginSignUp}/>
            <Route component={NotFound} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am able to hit the App component but I get an error saying `You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>` which I assume is coming from my nav component which is in `App.js` but since `App` itself is wrapped in the `<Router>` wouldn't it make sense that it's child components (and any subsequent links) would also be wrapped in `<Router>`?

Comment: It should, and if you;ve looked at the link you will see that this is the case. Look like it is done in the docs.

Comment: I checked out the link and it was helpful. Technically my `<Link/>`'s are in the `<Header/>` component but that is only being imported in `<App/>` and nowhere else. Like `<App/>` get's hit before `<Header/>`. Unless the `<Link/>` has to literally be in `<App/>` as opposed to a child of `<App/>`.

Comment: Is there any way I can have the other components be wrapped in `<App/>` using routes? I want the `<Header/>` in `<App/>` to be present on all pages and I was able to do this by making `App`'s path inclusive (not exact path) but this creates an issue where the URL can be `/not-valid-url` and then it would render the `<Header/>` and a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your code in this way.
And also check **path to app component** when importing

```
<Router history={history} store={store}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
    <Route exact path="/404" component={NotFound} />
    <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/games" component={Games} />
    <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
    <Route path="/games/:id" render={getGame} />
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginSignUp} />
  </Switch>
</Router>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this way but I get an error saying `You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>` which I assume is coming from my nav component which is in `App.js` but since `App` itself is wrapped in the `<Router>` wouldn't it make sense that it's child components (and any subsequent links) would also be wrapped in `<Router>`? Also what is the significance of using `exact path` for `Home` and `path` for `App`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route check it

Comment: yeah u r right if your  ```<Link/>``` is in app component then it should work

Comment: Technically it's in the `<Header/>` component but that is only being imported in `<App/>` and nowhere else. Like `<App/>` get's hit before `<Header/>`. Unless the `<Link/>` has to literally be in `<App/>` as opposed to a child of `<App/>`.

Comment: The switch doesn't maintain the `App` with the child components, it appears to show just `App`. When I removed the switch it worked better.