# Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>. But I already have the react-router-dom included in the import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from '../logo.svg';

export default class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <nav className = "navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark px-sm-5">

            <img src = {logo} alt = "store" className = 'navbar-brand'/>

          <ul className = "navbar-nav align-text-center">
            <li className = "navbar-nav ml-5">
                <Link to="/">product </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    )
  }
}
```

And this is the error i'm getting
[This is the link to the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM9pc.png)

[Error while I run the {npm start}, also there is not 'react-router-dom' folder when I looked into the "/node_modules/@types". I reinstalled npm install react-router-dom but I wasn't able to figure out the problem]

Comment: [You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640280/you-should-not-use-link-outside-a-router)

Comment: never mnd....I rwrapped the Link in <BrowserRouter><Link to.......></Link></BroswerRouter> and it worked.