# <Link> outside <Router> error message in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm trying to set a custom history object in my route to be able to use it my redux actions. I've seen that we should use `<Router>` from *'react-router'* and set the history object in it. That's what I've done.

**App.js**

```
//** Import router */
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Router } from 'react-router';

import history from './hooks/useHistory';

const App = () => {
   return (
      <Router history={history}>
         <MainNavigation />
         <Switch>
            <Routes />
         </Switch>
      </Router>
   );
};

export default App;
```

**MainNavigation.js**

```
const MainNavigation = () => {
   return (
      <>
         <div className='navigation'>
            <ul>
               <Link to='/'>
                  <li>Home</li>
               </Link>
               <Link to='/contact'>
                  <li>Contact</li>
               </Link>
               <Link to='/about'>
                  <li>A propos</li>
               </Link>
               <Link to='/user-profile'>
                  <li>Votre compte</li>
               </Link>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </>
   );
};

export default MainNavigation;
```

And Finally, the **Routes.js**

```
//** Import routers */
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Routes = () => {
   return (
      <>
         <Route path='/' exact component={MainLayout} />
         <Route path='/about' exact component={About} />
         <Route path='/contact' exact component={ContactForm} />
         <Route path='/user-profile' exact component={UserAccount} />
         <Redirect to='/' />
      </>
   );
};

export default Routes;
```

I don't understand why it says **You should not use `<Link>` outside a `<Router>`** as the component which includes the `<link>` (MainNavigation.js) is inside the `<Router>` tags.

Comment: I can't test right now, as I'm at work, but shouldn't the <Router> come from `react-router-dom` as well ? Like in the docs https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing

Comment: Also, there's a guide about using redux with the history, and a dedicated library for it at the end. It might be something to look into

Comment: @JulienRipet I thought too but it seems that this is another thing. If you want on use custom history object you should use Router as mentionned in this doc https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router. And thank you I'll look into the guide.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to use BrowserRouter or one of the others ones according to the good answers here: [You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640280/you-should-not-use-link-outside-a-router)

And one other thing: try to put your `li` elements outside of your `<Link>` tags, so that you have `ul > li > Link`

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've tried this but then, when I try to use history.push() in my actions the url updates but the component doesn't render. I look in the doc that has been sent above.

Comment: Are you using React-Router's useHistory hook?

Comment: in my useHistory file I've put this: `import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const myHistory = createBrowserHistory();` PS: I've changed a bit the names but the logic is the same