# Navigation links not working ReactJS Router v6

Tags: reactjs

This code doesn't work. I am using React Router v6

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Good</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contactus">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/aboutus">Users</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<h1>Harsh</h1>} />
          <Route path="/layout" element={<Layout />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="contactus" element={<ContactUs />} />
          <Route path="aboutus" element={<AboutUs />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

But it starts working when the navigation links are rendered by some other component. I wish not to have a separate component for navigation links...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
/*
Nav links placed in Layout.tsx 
*/
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="contactus" element={<ContactUs />} />
          <Route path="aboutus" element={<AboutUs />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You must render nav link inside the Router tree to work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48640280/you-should-not-use-link-outside-a-router

Answer (score -1):

At first, all react router dom components are wrapped in the browserRouter component.

This code doesn't work. I am using React Router v6

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <h1>Good</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contactus">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/aboutus">Users</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
   
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<h1>Harsh</h1>} />
          <Route path="/layout" element={<Layout />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="contactus" element={<ContactUs />} />
          <Route path="aboutus" element={<AboutUs />} />
        </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Same as my question here. Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71868736/router-does-not-work-with-link-react-router-dom-6#71868769