# React Router Switch not rendering specific component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have a React app that is currently using react-router@4.2.0 and I'm struggling with rendering a specific component when the URL changes.

When I try to visit `/locations/new` it returns with a PropTypes error from the CityList component. I have tried adding in `exact` to the Route component within LocationsWrapper and then Main config too, however, this then influences other routes - such as `/locations` to become null.

// BrowserRouter

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import store from "./store";
import Navbar from "./components/Core/Navbar";
import Routes from "./config/routes";

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#FCFCFC" }}>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

// Router config - ( Routes )

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "../components/Home";
import Locations from "../components/Locations";
import CityList from "../components/CityList";
import CreateLocation from "../components/CreateLocation";
import Locale from "../components/Locale/index";
import Profile from "../components/Profile";
import NoMatch from "../components/Core/NoMatch";

import requireAuth from "../components/Core/HOC/Auth";

const LocationsWrapper = () => (
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/locations" component={Locations} />
    <Route path="/locations/new" component={CreateLocation} />
    <Route path="/locations/:id" component={CityList} />
  </div>
);

const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={requireAuth(Home)} />
      <Route path="/locations" component={LocationsWrapper} />
      <Route path="/locale/:id" component={Locale} />
      <Route path="/profile" component={requireAuth(Profile, true)} />
      <Route component={NoMatch} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
);

export default Main;
```

Am I best avoiding `<Switch>` entirely and implementing a new method for routes that are undefined - such as 404s?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested routes with react router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will definitely return first

```
<Route path="/locations/:id" component={CityList} />
```

In react-router 4 there is no concept of index route, it will check each and every routes so in your defining routes are same

```
<Route path="/locations/new" component={CreateLocation} />
<Route path="/locations/:id" component={CityList} />
```

both path are same `'/location/new'` and `'/location/:id'` so /new and /:id are same params.

so at last 'CityList' will return

You can define like this

```
<Route path="/locations/create/new" component={CreateLocation} />
<Route path="/locations/list/:id" component={CityList} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your route is not working cause you are also matching params with /locations/new with /locations/:id so then 'new' becomes Id param.

Try changing this

```
   <Route path="/locations/new" component={CreateLocation} />
```

To something like this

```
   <Route path="/locs/new" component={CreateLocation} />
```

Just a suggestion hope this may help

Comment: It should work as it is, `new` is defined before `:id`

Comment: I've tried adding `exact` and `exact strict` to the path=".../new" route, however that still tries to render the CityList component - to no avail