# react-router pass previous routes props to sub route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to pass props from the Parent component down to the Child component using react-router?

```
<Route path="/parent/" component={Parent} />
<Route path="/parent/child/" component={Child} />
```

Notice Child is not rendered in the Parent's render function.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have a hierarchy like this in the first place?

Comment: Maybe its a dumb idea, but I had components that were consistent across all child route of parent (such as header, footer) rendered in parent. That way it didn't have to re-render on all child route changes.

Comment: So you should use a Route within Parent. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4

Answer (score 1):

I think a good solution here would be nested routes with render props.

```
// Parent.jsx

render() {
  const { match: { url }, xyz } = this.props;
  return (
    <Route path={`${url}/child`} render={() => <Child xyz={xyz} />}
  );
}
```

Comment: In your example, how would I pass parent state into the <Child /> component, such that when the Parent's state changes the <Child /> component would be updated (i.e. it would receive the parent's state changes as props)

Comment: So instead of extracting xyz from this.props you could extract any values from state too and pass them down to <Child />

Comment: Ah, I implemented a custom componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState), the problem was my component was not updating with some new state in some cases.