# react-router-redux - how to do nested routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

How do you get nested routing with react-router-redux (5.0.0-alpha.9)?

I want to be able to route to the likes of `/event/create`
I am able to successfully get to a route of `/event/:id`, e.g. `/event/1234`

I have -

```
<Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
<Route path="/event/:id" component={EventView} />
<Route path="/event/create" component={EventCreate} />
```

It looks as though when I go to `/event/create` is routing to `/event/:id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested routes with react router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Router will return on the first match. In your case, you simply need to move the last two statements as :id will match on anything:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
<Route path="/event/create" component={EventCreate} />
<Route path="/event/:id" component={EventView} />
```

This will match on /event/create first and if there's any other value, it will match on the subsequent route.