# React Router Nested Routes?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router

So I have a React application which has the main routes of

```
/
/projects
/gallery
/about
```

I want to have a nested route that looks like

```
/projects/skout
```

I am not sure why, but this route is not rendering the proper HTML from the respective component file. It is just empty.

#### App Component

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.child = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {

    let routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/projects/skout" Component={Skout} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projects} />
        <Route exact path="/gallery" component={Gallery} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Redirect exact to="/" />
      </Switch>
    )

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App" styleName="main-wrapper">
          <Layout>
              {routes}
          </Layout>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>

    );
  }
}

export default CSSModules(App, styles);
```

#### Skout Component

```
import React from 'react';

const skout = (props) => (
    <div>
        <span className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <h1>
                    Gallery
                </h1>
            </div>
            <span className="container">
                <p>
                    Storage for Photos, Ideas, and Thoughts
                </p>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
)

export default skout;
```

Do I have to put a route inside the `/projects` component?

Comment: `<Redirect exact to="/" />`

Comment: Are you using `react-router v4`?

Comment: yep react router v4.3.1 @Abinthaha

Comment: Did you try this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4

Answer (score 0):

You need to render matched route component inside `Layout` as they are nested routes:

```
  export const Layout = ({ children }) => (
     <React.Fragment>
            {children}
     </React.Fragment>
   )
```

But in react router v4, nested routes needs to render separately. You need put routes inside Layout components.