# React query strings take more than 1 parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

I'm working with React.js Router and trying to achieve this:

Users go to a `module` then a `level` and the url will look like this:
`myapp.com/game/module/some-module/level/level-1`.
I need to handle all different `module` and `level` like this:

`/module/:name
/level/:name`

so I don't need to specify each url several times.

Here's the code in `App.js`:

```
const App = () =>
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/game" component={Game} />
            <Route exact path="/module/:name" component={Module} />
            <Route exact path="/level/:name" component={Level} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>

export default App
```

I know I can "grab" the value of module name in the child like this: `match.params.name`.

How do I do it in React?
Do you have a better approach than this?

e.g. `/game/some-module/some-level`, in this case, how do you pass the `module name` and `level name` in the `Route`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Level route should be nested inside the Module component.

Here's a similar discussion on Stack Overflow: [Nested routes with react router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)

And here's a good blog post that explains how nested routes work in React Router v4: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-nested-routes/