# How to create route like ( domain.com / dashboard/products ) In React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to ReactJS . I want to make route which may like `(dashboard/product)` . How it would be possible . I created but it not working properly .. could some please help me . 
Thanks .

```
<div style={wrapperStyle.MainWrapper}>
      <h1>Dashboard Page</h1>

      <div style={wrapperStyle.leftSideMenues}>
          <h1>Left Side Menues</h1>
          <div>

          </div>
      </div>
      <Router>
              <Switch>
                  <Route path='/' exact component= {Dashboard}/>
                  <Route path='/dashboard/:organizationContact' component={OraganizationContacts}/>
                  <Route path='/dashboard/products' component={Products}/>
                  <Route path='/sales' component={Sales}/>
                  <Route path='/purchase_orders' component={PurchaseOrders}/>
                  <Route path='/shipment' component={Shipments}/>
                  <Route path='/everything' component={Everything}/>
                  <Route path='/reports' component={Reports}/>
                  <Route path='/settings' component={Settings}/>
                  <Route path='/logout' component={LogOut}/>
                  <Route component={NotFound}/>
              </Switch>
          </Router>
  </div>
```

Comment: You might wanna look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reorder routes as following:

```
<Route exact path='/dashboard/products' component={Products}/>
<Route exact path='/dashboard/:organizationContact' component={OraganizationContacts}/>
```

Comment: You mean to say that I should add `exact` with all routes ?

Comment: Yes in react-router4 routes are matched using regex, so by adding `exact` it matches the exact route.

Comment: For example In Route . If User Click on `dashboard/user` I just want to display `User` Component Data . Now It showing both component data . How to avoid dashboard component data ?

Comment: If route is `dashboard/user`, as per routes it should go to `OraganizationContacts` component