# Why does the whole DOM re-render when navigating between routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am learning react so forgive me if this has been asked a million times but I have browsed and no solution has fixed my issue. Apart from fixing the issue I would like to understand how the mechanics under the hood work...

I have 2 simple components `NavBar` and `Home`. Code below for both.

`NavBar`:

```
import React from "react";

class NavBar extends React.Component {
    render () {

        return (

            <nav className="navbar sticky-top navbar-light" style={NavBarStyle}>
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <img src={require('./av_tiny.png')} style={ImageStyle} alt="Logo"></img>
                </a>
            </nav>
        )
    }

}

const NavBarStyle = {
    // some styling
}

const ImageStyle = {
    width: '100px',
    height: '50px',
    marginLeft: '20px'
}

export default NavBar;
```

`Home`:

```
import React from "react";

class Home extends React.Component {
    render(){

        return(
            <h1>Home</h1>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

When I navigate between routes, the whole DOM re-renders. I don't want the `NavBar` to re-render. My routes are declared in `App.js` as per below, and I have tried moving `<NavBar />` outside the `<Router>` tags and the other way around. I have also tried putting `<NavBar />` in its own `<div>` tags. Still the app behaves the same, whenever I change the URL it re-renders everything. How can this be avoided and what should I read up to properly understand the mechanics?

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";

//individual components
import Home from "./Home";
import SignInPage from "./Components/Login";
import NavBar from "./Components/Layout/NavBar"

//Routing to components
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return(
          <div>
            <NavBar/>
            <Router>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={SignInPage}/>      
            </Router>
          </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

EDIT:

I think I should've mentioned that re-renders happen when I navigate by manually changing the URL in the browser. I have some code on my `/login` route that does `this.props.history.push('/');` after successful login and the DOM does not re-render. Just `{SignInPage}` gets unmounted and `{Home}` gets mounted. I would expect the same behavior when navigating between the pages manually or am I missing something?

Comment: It's mentioned in the [very first section](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start): `Note: Instead of <a href="/"> we use <Link to="/">.`

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I have removed the `href and <a>` bit from my `NavBar` completely, and it still behaves the same. I suspect my `App.js` routing is wrong..

Comment: When you say the whole DOM rerenders, do you mean the `<head>` portion too?

Comment: Yes, so if I open dev tools in the browser I see the whole DOM being added again, like a page reload. the HTML completely disappears and reappears. I have added an EDIT where I mention that this doesn't happen in a certain situation

Comment: Please put your changed code in the question so we can see what you're doing. I built a demo based on your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-smoke-qjmhh

Comment: Thanks Chris, when you click the `Login` in your example it transitions without a re-render. However if you change the URL manually to `https://qjmhh.codesandbox.io/login` it re-renders everything. Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `<a>` elements to create your links. These cause the browser to navigate to the new URL without triggering the JavaScript that would cause the content to be dynamically updated using React.

Use the [`<Link>` component](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html) from whatever React Router library you are using instead.

---

Further reading:

- [Anchor tags vs Link components in React](https://markadamfoster.com/posts/react-anchor-tags-vs-link-components/)

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I have removed the `href and <a>` bit from my `NavBar` completely, and it still behaves the same. I suspect my App.js routing is wrong in some way..

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it re-renders hole dom is that the router is changing root properties.

Take a look at nested routers, it will give you an idea of how to achieve your goal [Nested routes with react router v4 / v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4-v5)