# react router - navigation to a different route fo same component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route /users and /users/:pageNumber that leads to the same component (A table of users).
When I navigate from /users to /users/3 using `hashHistory.push('/users/3')` The component will not reload with adjusting to the new parameters, the router assumes I'm already in the right place...

How can I make the component reload with the new parameters?

---

Routes are defined as follows:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
    <Route path="/" component={MainContainer}>
      <Route onEnter={validateToken} path="users" component={UsersManagement}/>
      <Route onEnter={validateToken} path="users/:pageNumber" component={UsersManagement}/>
    </Route>
 </Router>
</Provider>
```

Comment: Post your Routes.

Comment: Just add `exact` prop to Route with `path="users"`.

Comment: does seem to have an effect, note that both paths lead to the same component, but with a different param of pagination

Comment: Are you working on `react-router-v4`?

Comment: no, im on v3, upgrading now

Comment: Before upgrading check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4-v5. `react-router-v4` don't support nested routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like -:

```
if(this.props.match.params.pageNumber === 3){
    //Re-route the page.
}
```