# React router long nested routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Question about routing, i want to have this structure:

`/admin/:userId/settings/:settingId`

How to setup router for this case? I tried this:

```
<Route exact path="/admin/:userId">
                user
                <Route exact path="/settings/:settingId">
                    setting
                </Route>
            </Route>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested routes with react router v4 / v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4-v5)

Comment: use link rather router <Route exact path="/admin/:userId">

Answer (score 1):

you can use in this situation the link
look

```
<Link exact path="/admin/:userId"><a>useer<a><Link/>
<Link exact path="/settings/:settingId"><a>Setting<a><Link/>
```

you should add this in the router
as this

```
<Route exact path="/admin/:userId" component={userId} />
<Route exact path="/admin/:userId/settings/:settingId" component= {settingsId} />
```

Answer (score 0):

### Like this

Each part you render other component.

```
<Route exact path="/admin" component={admin} />
<Route exact path="/admin/:userId" component={userId} />
<Route exact path="/admin/:userId/settings" component={settings} />
<Route exact path="/admin/:userId/settings/:settingId" component= {settingsId} />
```

And you also can each route inside his father component.