# React - Change component by the router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I start learning about React, and I am working in an application in two parts: when the user is logged and is not.

When the user is not logged, the "/" will show the login page. When is logged, will show the Dashboard page. In Dashboard page, there is a top nav and a sidebar in the left, and in the "center" will show the content of the page. Linke in this image from [iMaster](https://imasters.com.br/front-end/gerenciando-rotas-com-react-router):

[image]

SO the sidebar will have links, that will update the component that is shown as children of the Dashboard component. I searched about "Nested Routes", but no success.

I'm trying to do in this because I see that if I will show the navs in "all" pages, is better load the navs one time and then update the children os the navs, instead of loading the navs in every page.

Anyone can help?

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './pages/login';
import Dashboard from './pages/dashboard';

const App = () => (

    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </div>

);

export default App;
```

**Dashboard**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//BOOTSTRAP
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
//BOOTSTRAP

import './styles.css';
import TopSideNavBar from '../../components/TopSideNavBar';


export default class Dashboard extends Component {

    render() {

        return(

            <>

            <div className="body">

                <TopSideNavBar />

                <Container fluid className="content">
                 <Switch>
         <Route path={`${match.path}/component1`} render={Component1}/>
         <Route path={`${match.path}/component2`} render={Component2}/>
                 </switch>
                </Container>

            </div>


            </>

        );

    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see where you render left sidebar and how is it implemented. can you show it?

Comment: The official documentation has an example of [nesting](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting). It just comes down to putting `Route` components inside of other `Route`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested routes with react router v4 / v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4-v5)

Comment: @ValeryStatinov I'm rendering in the Dashboard (see code) as a component. The code of this component is very big, but is just html and css code. The left bar have a <ul> with <li>. Each li is a link to another page. When I click on a <li>, I wanna show the page/component as children of the Dashboard.

Comment: @SameerRezaKhan I tried the firts answer but no success. Probably because I'm noob and did something wrong :( The others answer I don't undestood, so I did not try.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I will check this, thanks.

Comment: I think you can do something like this inside <Container> ,  `<Switch><Route path={`${match.path}/route`} component={Component}/></switch>`

Comment: @SameerRezaKhan with your sample i get this error: 'match' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Please update your code with the latest one

Comment: @Alex code updated. If we can chat please send a message and I will explain more!

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206398/alex-react-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your component with `BrowserRouter`  and correct access to `match.path`

```
export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
       <>

            <div className="body">

            <TopSideNavBar />
            <Switch>
            <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/component1`} component={Component1} />
            <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/component2`} component={Component2} />
           </Switch>
           </div>


       </>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```