# How to fix 'exact' routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a new route inside of 'Form' but cannot do it without affecting the 'Businesses' route I had previously created (the 'Business' route will not appear at all). I read the documentation but couldn't really figure out how to solve this problem but I'm assuming it's because of the two 'exact path'.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/"> 
    <Form />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/booking">
    <Booking />
  </Route>
</Switch>

//inside of <Form/>

<Switch>
  <Route exact path ="/"> 
    <Selection/>
  </Route>
  <Route path ="/businesses/:businessesId"> 
    <Businesses/>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Please refer to this answer from a question about nested routes https://stackoverflow.com/a/43311025/7238376

Comment: What it makes sense to have two `Route`s with `path="/"` but the two render different components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets first think about what logic is currently in place. `<Switch>` does exactly what you might guess (similar to a normal `switch` statement), and it returns the first `<Route>` match inside. To help visualize, lets remove the JSX and just use logical operators.

You currently have the equivalent to this pseudo code:

```js
switch(path) {
  case '/':
    switch(path) {
      case '/':
        return 'Form Component';
      case '/businesses/*':
        return 'Businesses Component';
    }
  case '/booking'
    return 'Booking Component';
  default:
    return null;
}
```

Can you see the problem?

Both the outer switch and the nested switch are trying to match the same `path`. Since the nested switch only gets triggered when the path is exactly `/`, the inner switch can only ever match that as well. As soon as you change the path to `/businesses`, the outer switch no longer matches `/`, so your nested switch never gets a chance to match the path.

There are a few ways to fix this, and the correct way will depend on your specific needs and preferences.

The first is do follow something like what @faithfull has described. Put all of your `<Route>`'s on the same level. This would change your logic to this pseudo code:

```js
switch(path) {
  case '/':
    return 'Form Component';
  case '/businesses/*':
    return 'Businesses Component';
  case '/booking'
    return 'Booking Component';
  default:
    return null;
}
```

However this won't work if your requirement is to have nested routes. If you need the second switch to be nested, then simply remove the `exact` prop from the outer switch. But this alone will cause other issues. A `<Switch>` only renders its **first** match. So removing the `exact` prop will cause the `/` path to always be the first match. You'll need to move this to the bottom of your switch so that the other `<Route>`'s have a chance to match first:

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path="/booking">
    <Booking />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/"> 
    <Form />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Then you can leave the nested router as is and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do something like:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/"> 
    <Form />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/booking">
    <Booking />
  </Route>
  <Route path ="/businesses/:businessesId"> 
    <Businesses />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

And then in your Form.tsx

```
import Selection from '...';
class Form extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      {/*some other Form jsx*/}
      {Selection}
    );
  }
}
```