# When Parent is inside <Route/> child <Route/>s are not working in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I have below code in my App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>

            {/* <CaseDetailsController /> */}   //Rendering directly

            <Switch>
                <Route path='/check'>
                    <CaseDetailsController />}
                </Route>
           </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

I have `<CaseDetailsController />` component which I want to render when my URL is - '/check'.

And `<CaseDetailsController>` has a child `<CaseDetails>` which has a section that renders components based on  value from below logic.

```
<Switch>
                    {
                        Routes.map((x, y) => {
                            console.log(x.redirectUrl, x.component)
                            return (
                                <Route key={y} path={x.redirectUrl} component={x.component} />
                            )

                        })
                    }
                </Switch>
```

My internal child routing works fine when I am writing `CaseDetailsController` directly. But when I put it inside `<Route>` the navigation works from `CaseDetailsController` but routing stops working for its child i.e. `<CaseDetails>`.

What is the problem here?

Comment: This question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4-v5

Comment: @AlexandarZaharyan - It seems a different issue to me.

Comment: @PushpendraYadav please elaborate why the provided link does not fully solve your problem

Comment: It got fixed when I added my child routing as `/check/child1`. Earlier it was like /child1