# React child nested routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to achieve child/nested routes in Reactjs and below are the 2 methods which I found for nesting the child routes but parent routes work fine and child routes for Parent component do not.

Below are the routes how it works:

```
/ => Home Component
/login => Login Component
/register => Register Componet

/product/ => ProductListing Component 
/product/2 => ProductDetails Component [Expected but does not work]
/product/2/edit => ProductEdit Component [Expected but does not work]
```

---

## Method 1

Below is my Main Route File:

```
export default function MainRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route exact path="/product" component={ProductRouter} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

and child route for Product as shown below in ProductRouter.js file

```
export default function ProductRouter(props) {
  console.log(props);

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path={`${props.match.path}/:productId`}
        component={ProductDetails}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path={`${props.match.path}/:productId/edit`}
        component={ProductEdit}
      />
      <Route exact path={`${props.match.path}`} component={ProductListing} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

---

## Method 2

Below is my Main Route File:

```
export default function MainRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route exact path="/product/*" component={ProductRouter} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

and child route for Product as shown below in ProductRouter.js file

```
export default function ProductRouter(props) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Route exact path="/" component={ProductListing} />
      <Route
        exact
        path=":productId"
        component={ProductDetails}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path=":productId/edit"
        component={ProductEdit}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Below are the links I checked:

- [Stackoverflow: Nested routes with react router v4 / v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4-v5)
- https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#introducing-routes

Comment: `parent routes work fine and child routes for Parent component do not` how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exact` prop on root route will exclude any sub-routes, they won't render because the root route no longer matches.

[Nesting Routes](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting)

You need to remove the `exact` prop from the root routes (keep it on the home route so it doesn't *always* match)

```
export default function MainRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route path="/product" component={ProductRouter} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Use the correct path prefix (you can remove the exact prop, the `Switch` will only render the first match

```
export default function ProductRouter(props) {
  console.log(props);
  const { match: { path } } = props;

  return (
    <Switch>
      // specify more specific path before less specific path
      <Route path={`${path}/:productId/edit`} component={ProductEdit} />
      <Route path={`${path}/:productId`} component={ProductDetails} />
      <Route path={path} component={ProductListing} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks @drew-reese but  instead of using switch in child routes and using exact for all child routes, also works fine but in parent as you said we have to remove exact