# react rendering nested child routes when specifying only parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a parent container that has this route

```
const App = () => {
    return ( <
        ProtectedRoute exact path = {
            `/parent`
        }
        redirectTo = "/welcome"
        component = {
            ParentComp
        }
        />
    )
}
```

In parent Comp:

```
const ParentComp = (props) => ( <>
  <StaticStuff/>
  <ProtectedRoute exact path = {`/:id`}
        redirectTo = "/welcome"
        component = {
            childComponent
        } 
</>)
```

Then in parent component I render a static text and a child component in a child path

When I trigger `Parent route` route inside `<StaticStuff>` I also see the content of children Component. but What I'm trying to do is only show `StaticStuff`component then when triggering `/parent/DynamicParam` then will see it under `Static Stuff`.

Here's the content of `Protected Route`

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => {
        return isAuthorized() ? <Component {...rest} {...props} /> :
            <Redirect to={{
                pathname: props.redirectTo,
                state: {
                    from: props.location
                }
            }} />
    }
    }>
    </Route>)
```

Answer (score -1):

So your `ParentComp` is displayed when the route equals `/parent`. Now you have a route inside the parent component with params (`/:id`) which obviously is also triggered by the route `/parent` with `id=parent`.

So either nest the route in the ParentComp (e.g. `/parent/:id`) or use a query parameter to display the child component conditionally.

Comment: Do you mean as I do it actually ? I'm nesting the child route in Parent

Comment: No, only nesting Route Components does not automatically nest the path. You need to include the existing matching path `/parent` in the route. See an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43311025/10696402