# how to render separated routes in different components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hello how can i render routes which are actually separated on different component for example my Dashboard has 2 routes with 2 components inside and my App.js is having all the rest.
and also i'm having trouble to redirect to the /login from inside dashboard it doesn't redirect (i used history.push("/login")) from inside dashbord

UPDATE :

my code looks like that
dashboard.js component

```
<Router>
....mycomponent
<switch>
<Route path="/cutomers"><CutomersComponent><Route>
<Route path="/sales"><SalesComponent><Route>
</switch>
</Router>
```

app.js component

```
<Router>
....mycomponent
<switch>
<Route path="/login"><Login><Route>
<Route path="/dashbord"><Dashbord><Route>
</switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: please show the code of what you have tried so far

Comment: my code is updated now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested routes with react router v4 / v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4-v5)

Answer (score 1):

solution was simply by migrating from react router v5 to react router v6 here's a github repo which i made with explanation

https://github.com/w4t3r-45/react-router-v6