# How to add sub paths in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a index file where I have

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={Home}
    <Route path="/home/student/info" element={Info} />
    <Route path="/home/student/about" element={about} />
    <Route path="/home/teacher/score" element={score} />
    <Route path="/home/teacher/attendence" element={attendence} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Here, I have this common path for `"/home/student/"`. So How can I use a react sub path for this, rather than writing separate lines? I'm using `react-router` 6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested routes with react router v4 / v5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4-v5)

Answer (score 4):

You can use nested routes. Put routes as children of the route component. Don't forget that in RRDv6 the `element` prop takes a `ReactNode`, e.g. JSX, and not a reference to a React component like v5.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="home">
      <Route path="student">
        <Route path="info" element={<Info />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="teacher">
        <Route path="score" element={<Score />} />
        <Route path="attendence" element={<Attendence />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

You can read more about nested routes [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#nested-routes).

Comment: can we write one component for 

 <Route path="info" element={<Info />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
for this and that we will load inside this file

Comment: this does not work, it says  route is only ever to be used as the child of Routes element, never rendered directly.Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes/>