# React router V6 <NavLink to="/" /> is always active

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have defined a few routes:

```
const MainRoutes = {
  path: "/",
  element: <MainLayout />,
  children: [
    {
      index: true,
      element: <DashboardDefault />,
    },
    {
      path: "werknemers",
      element: <Werknemers />
    },
    {
      path: "verzuimdossiers",
      element: <Verzuimdossiers />
    }
  ],
};
```

My `<MainLayout />` contains the Sidebar, Header and Outlet. In my Sidebar, I have a few `<NavLinks/>` like so:

```
<NavLink exact to="/" className={({ isActive })=> (isActive ? `active ${LINK_CLASSES}` : `inactive ${LINK_CLASSES}`)}>
  <span>Dashboard</span>
</NavLink>
<NavLink to="werknemers" className={({ isActive })=> (isActive ? `active ${LINK_CLASSES}` : `inactive
  ${LINK_CLASSES}`)}>
  <span>Werknemers</span>
</NavLink>
<NavLink to="verzuimdossiers" className={({ isActive })=> (isActive ? `active ${LINK_CLASSES}` : `inactive
  ${LINK_CLASSES}`)}>
  <span>Verzuimdossiers</span>
</NavLink>
```

However, my `<NavLink/>` for the root "/" is always active. The other 2 work just fine. If I am on "/werknemers" I do not want the Dashboard route to be also active...

What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you put `exact` at the other links as well?

Comment: @node_modules It does not solve the problem :(

Comment: In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71849055/6060964) I saw an answer regarding `exact` in React Router V6, they have changed it to `end` apparently. Can you try that?

Comment: @node_modules Yay! That works. They keep on changing everything with the router. You can make an answer and I'll accept it if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In React Router you were using `exact` property to exactly match the URL in the browser. However, this only works in V5. In V6, they have changed it to `end` instead. So you have to do something like this:

```html
<NavLink end to="/messages">Link</NavLink>
```

Reference documentation upgrading from V5 to V6: https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.1/upgrading/v5#rename-navlink-exact-to-navlink-end